# jQuery UI Sortable - Change cursor when dragging out from the sortable list

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm using JQuery UI to implement drag-drop in a sortable list and am trying to change the cursor when dragging out from the list. I've tried the following but the cursor doesn't change. However the border colour changes to red as expected.

```
$('#sortable').sortable({
    out: function (e, ui) {
        ui.item.css('cursor', 'move');          //this has no effect!
        ui.item.css('border', '1px solid red'); //this works
    }
});
```

How can I change the cursor when dragging out from the list? Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: I've created a fiddle as requested (http://jsfiddle.net/muc17tw5/1/) but to my surprise it's working in the fiddle! So the issue must be with my application code. I will need to investigate further.

Comment: could you provide a fiddle?

Comment: What about a CSS style in **:hover**, **:focus**, **:active** ?

Comment: Can you provide the scenario (running program)? Have you tried :hover on desired selector?

Comment: Would advise adding a Class when `out` is triggered. The CSS for that class should then contain the Cursor properties you desire.